# Parsing a webpage for indexing

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am trying to understand/optimize the logic for indexing a site. I am new to HTML/JS side of things and so am learning as I go. While indexing a site, I recursively go deeper into the site based on the links on each page. One problem is pages have repeating URLs and text like the header and footer. For the URLs I have a list of URLs I have already processed. Is there something I can do for identifying the text that repeats on each page? I hope my explanation is clear enough. I currently have the code (in python) to get a list of useful URLs for that site. Now I am trying to index the content of these pages. Is there a preferred logic to identify or skip repeating text on these pages (like headers, footers, other blurb). I am using BeautifulSoup + the requests module.

Comment: @johnthexiii -- Is there a way to tell what the edits are for the post?

Comment: click on the blue timestamp above my name, I removed the signature(SO doesn't like those) and you misspelled a word.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that SO does not like signatures.

Comment: Yea they've got a lot of funny rules, here is the pertinent faq [section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) on signatures. You should check out the rest of the faq if you get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are hoping for, but readability is a popular service that just parses the "useful" content from a page.  This is the service that is integrated into safari for ios.

It intelligently gets the worthwhile content of the page while ignorning things like footer/header/ads/etc

There are open source ports for python/ruby/php and probably other languages.

https://github.com/buriy/python-readability

Comment: Interesting. This is probably what I am looking for. I have to go through the code as I would like to understand what exactly is being done so that I can better fit it into my code. Thanks for your help.